# How to run Faust from Docker - ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-rocksdb

Tags: python, docker, faust

I'm trying to run Python Faust from Docker.

Based on this documentation: https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/installation.html

I created a simple Docker file:

```
FROM python:3

ADD ./app/app.py /

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -U faust

RUN pip install "faust[rocksdb]"

RUN pip install "faust[rocksdb,uvloop,fast,redis]"

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

When I create a docker file I receive an error at the 5th stage (Step 5/7 : RUN pip install "faust[rocksdb]")

> ---> Running in 1e42a5e50cbe Requirement already satisfied:
> faust[rocksdb] in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.10.4)
> Requirement already satisfied: terminaltables<4.0,>=3.1 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (3.1.10)
> Requirement already satisfied: click<8.0,>=6.7 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (7.1.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (1.7.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp-cors<2.0,>=0.7 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (0.7.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: mypy-extensions in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (0.4.3)
> Requirement already satisfied: colorclass<3.0,>=2.2 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (2.2.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: opentracing<2.0.0,>=1.3.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (1.3.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: mode<4.4,>=4.3.2 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (4.3.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: venusian<2.0,>=1.1 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (1.2.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<4.0,>=3.5.2 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (3.8.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: robinhood-aiokafka<1.2,>=1.1.6 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (1.1.6)
> Requirement already satisfied: croniter>=0.3.16 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from faust[rocksdb]) (1.1.0)
> Collecting python-rocksdb>=0.6.7   Downloading
> python-rocksdb-0.7.0.tar.gz (219 kB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py):
> started   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
> Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> aiohttp<4.0,>=3.5.2->faust[rocksdb]) (1.2.0) Requirement already
> satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
> (from aiohttp<4.0,>=3.5.2->faust[rocksdb]) (21.2.0) Requirement
> already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> aiohttp<4.0,>=3.5.2->faust[rocksdb]) (1.2.0) Requirement already
> satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> aiohttp<4.0,>=3.5.2->faust[rocksdb]) (2.0.9) Requirement already
> satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> aiohttp<4.0,>=3.5.2->faust[rocksdb]) (5.2.0) Requirement already
> satisfied: async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> aiohttp<4.0,>=3.5.2->faust[rocksdb]) (4.0.2) Requirement already
> satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
> (from croniter>=0.3.16->faust[rocksdb]) (2.8.2) Requirement already
> satisfied: colorlog>=2.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
> (from mode<4.4,>=4.3.2->faust[rocksdb]) (6.6.0) Requirement already
> satisfied: setuptools>=25 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
> (from python-rocksdb>=0.6.7->faust[rocksdb]) (57.5.0) Requirement
> already satisfied: kafka-python<1.5,>=1.4.6 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> robinhood-aiokafka<1.2,>=1.1.6->faust[rocksdb]) (1.4.7) Requirement
> already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> yarl<2.0,>=1.0->faust[rocksdb]) (3.3) Requirement already satisfied:
> six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> python-dateutil->croniter>=0.3.16->faust[rocksdb]) (1.16.0)

And an **ERROR PART**:

> Building
> wheels for collected packages: python-rocksdb   Building wheel for
> python-rocksdb (setup.py): started   ERROR: Command errored out with
> exit status 1:    command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os,
> sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b8y7g4hs/python-rocksdb_b1c08993fd134ac4bc59e6f5d18bcd91/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b8y7g4hs/python-rocksdb_b1c08993fd134ac4bc59e6f5d18bcd91/setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-9_o4ek6z
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-b8y7g4hs/python-rocksdb_b1c08993fd134ac4bc59e6f5d18bcd91/
> Complete output (64 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build
> running build_py   creating build   creating
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10   creating
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/interfaces.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/errors.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying
> rocksdb/merge_operators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
> copying rocksdb/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/tests   copying
> rocksdb/tests/test_memtable.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/tests   copying
> rocksdb/tests/test_db.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/tests
> copying rocksdb/tests/**init**.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/tests   copying
> rocksdb/tests/test_options.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/tests   running egg_info   writing
> python_rocksdb.egg-info/PKG-INFO   writing dependency_links to
> python_rocksdb.egg-info/dependency_links.txt   writing requirements to
> python_rocksdb.egg-info/requires.txt   writing top-level names to
> python_rocksdb.egg-info/top_level.txt   reading manifest file
> 'python_rocksdb.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest template
> 'MANIFEST.in'   writing manifest file
> 'python_rocksdb.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'   copying rocksdb/_rocksdb.cpp
> -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/*rocksdb.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/backup.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/cache.pxd ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/comparator.pxd
> -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/db.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/env.pxd ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying
> rocksdb/filter_policy.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
>
> copying rocksdb/iterator.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
>
> copying rocksdb/logger.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
>
> copying rocksdb/memtablerep.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
> copying rocksdb/merge_operator.pxd ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/options.pxd ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying rocksdb/slice*.pxd ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying
> rocksdb/slice_transform.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
> copying rocksdb/snapshot.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
> copying rocksdb/status.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
> copying rocksdb/std_memory.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb
> copying rocksdb/table_factory.pxd ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   copying
> rocksdb/universal_compaction.pxd ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   creating
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/cpp   copying
> rocksdb/cpp/comparator_wrapper.hpp ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/cpp   copying
> rocksdb/cpp/filter_policy_wrapper.hpp ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/cpp   copying
> rocksdb/cpp/memtable_factories.hpp ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/cpp   copying
> rocksdb/cpp/merge_operator_wrapper.hpp ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/cpp   copying
> rocksdb/cpp/slice_transform_wrapper.hpp ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/cpp   copying
> rocksdb/cpp/utils.hpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/cpp
> copying rocksdb/cpp/write_batch_iter_helper.hpp ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/cpp   running build_ext
> cythoning rocksdb/_rocksdb.pyx to rocksdb/_rocksdb.cpp
> /tmp/pip-install-b8y7g4hs/python-rocksdb_b1c08993fd134ac4bc59e6f5d18bcd91/.eggs/Cython-0.29.26-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File:
> /tmp/pip-install-b8y7g4hs/python-rocksdb_b1c08993fd134ac4bc59e6f5d18bcd91/rocksdb/_rocksdb.pyx
> tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)   building 'rocksdb._rocksdb' extension   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb   gcc -pthread
> -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c rocksdb/_rocksdb.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/rocksdb/_rocksdb.o -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall
> -Wextra -Wconversion -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-rtti   rocksdb/_rocksdb.cpp:705:10: fatal error: rocksdb/slice.h: No such
> file or directory
> 705 | #include "rocksdb/slice.h"
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   compilation terminated.   error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
> ----------------------------------------   Building wheel for python-rocksdb (setup.py): finished with status 'error'   ERROR:
> Failed building wheel for python-rocksdb

Can anyone help me to move on with this? I'd like to use Faust from Docker on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message, where it is clearly stated you are missing a header file:

> fatal error: rocksdb/slice.h: No such file or directory 705 | #include "rocksdb/slice.h" | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

Accordingly, you'll need to [build and install](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/INSTALL.md) RocksDB. This is separate from the installation of `faust[rocksdb]` with pip. That simply [installs `python-rocksdb`](https://github.com/robinhood/faust/blob/master/requirements/extras/rocksdb.txt), the Python interface to the underlying libraries.

There is even a (third-party) [RocksDB docker image based on Python 3.7 Slim](https://hub.docker.com/r/marcosschroh/rocksdb).

You could use that directly or take some tricks from the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/marcosschroh/docker-rocksdb/blob/master/Dockerfile) for that image.