# Is faust[rocksdb] a mandatory extension to be installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rocksdb, faust

I am working on microservices architecture and using kafka to communicate b/n microservices. I am using python faust to implement producers and consumers.

Is it mandatory to install faust[rocksdb] extension? When I install it, fails with a

**fatal error: rocksdb/slice.h: No such file or directory.**

What could be the impact I could see in production if I am not using rocksdb? If the package is mandatory to install how can I solve the issue? I had tried many answers, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RocksDB is not a required dependency of Faust. By default a Faust app saves changelogs to memory, [which is in their documentation](https://fauststream.com/en/latest/userguide/application.html?highlight=memory#application-parameters).

Some systems may have issues installing `faust[rocksdb]` but I've had success installing it inside a Docker container. I suggest reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501371/9852671) for more details since they're having the same issue with `slice.h`.

Be warned that the wheel on PyPi for `python-rocksdb` is outdated, you'll need to manually install a newer version from https://github.com/twmht/python-rocksdb. There are more features in its actively maintained fork (https://github.com/NightTsarina/python-rocksdb), but I only got that working inside an Ubuntu 22.04 container.

> What could be the impact I could see in production if I am not using rocksdb?

If your Faust application needs to frequently restart and your changelogs have a lot of activity, then you'll have to wait a while to wait for your app to update your local state. [This is also mentioned in the Faust documentation](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/tables.html#the-changelog). This wait time could range from a few seconds to minutes depending on how frequently your tables change.

Update (08/11/2022):
I have updated [faust-streaming's fork of python-rocksdb](https://github.com/faust-streaming/python-rocksdb), try this:

```
pip3 install faust-streaming-rocksdb
```

The C++ dependencies are bundled with this now and I'm able to install it onto Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of the fork.